# Safari CSS Text not showing

Tags: css, safari, concrete5

I've got a serious problem on safari browsers with this website
http://daskommunikationsstudio.at/

the problem is that it seems the text is not shown correctly and since i don't own an apple
i've got no real experience with safari.

maybe someone can give me a hint.

thanks a lot

andy

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the colors on safari/iphone.

Comment: i tried safari both on mac and ipad and unfortunatly no text is showing on the startpage nor on any other page!

Comment: thanks a lot dan, i'll give it a try and let you know ok? thx andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a font rendering issue. Changed the font-family, eventually you can use different font for Safari.

Comment: you were right, the problem was the font rendering. the .woff file could not be loaded by safari, so i took another .woff file with the same fontstyle and it worked - strange but true!!! thanks a lot!!!